# After verification how to log in directly using verification link

Tags: java, php, html, mysql

After sending the verification link, I just want that when I click the verification link, the session should go to the USER home page. Which means directly go to the main page, not into the login page. Once click the verification link, it should go the users main page without again any login.

Answer (score 0):

Once user click on verification link and you are confirmed that user is valid user you can run same code as your login code which redirect user to home page if username and password is valid else redirect user to login page.
Hope this help :)